# How many elements $a \in \Bbb{Z}_N$ such that $ax \equiv y \mod N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider the ring $\Bbb{Z}_N$ of arithmetic modulo $N$: $\{0,1,2, \ldots ,N-1\}.$

Given $x,y \in \Bbb{Z}_N,$ how many of the elements of $\Bbb{Z}_N$ when multiplied with $x \pmod{N}$ result in $y$? And how can we calculate what they are efficiently?

The answer is a function of $N, x$ and $y.$

For example if $N = 10,$ $x = 6$ and $y = 2,$ then there are two elements $\{2,7\}$:

1. $2x = 12 \pmod{10} = 2 = y.$
2. $7x = 42 \pmod {10} = 2 = y.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we are asking how many $a$ are there such that, for a given $x,y$, we have $ax \equiv y \mod n$. This falls under the [Linear Congruence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem), which states that there will be a solution only if $\gcd(x,n)|y$, and if there are any solutions, then there are exactly $\gcd(x,n)$ of them.

Further, it is very easy to find all solutions once one is known, and the Euclidean algorithm will quickly give one solution (if there is a solution).

**EDIT** *added content*

In a comment, the OP asks `Once one solution is known how do I find the others?`

On the one hand, if you'd clicked on the wiki link answers this in the third sentence (the first restates the problem, the second gives the gcd requirement for a solution, and the third gives all the solutions). On the other, self-contained answers are usually simply better.

First one uses the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Description) to find a solution. In this case, it's often called the extended Euclidean Algorithm, as one uses it to find $\gcd(x,n)$, then 'extends it' to find integers $\alpha, \beta$ s.t. $\alpha x + \beta n = \gcd(x,n)$. If $\gcd(x,n)|y$, then in particular $y = c\gcd(x,n)$ for some $c$. But then $c\alpha x + c \beta n = y$, giving that $c\alpha x \equiv y \mod n$. So $c \alpha$, which I will now call $a_0$ is a solution: $a_0 x \equiv y \mod n$.

To get all the other solutions, one looks at $\left\{ a_0 + k \dfrac{n}{\gcd(x,n)} \right\}$ across $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let's check:

$\left(a_0 + \dfrac{kn}{\gcd(x,n)}\right)x = a_0x + \dfrac{kx}{\gcd(x,n)}n \equiv a_0x \equiv y \mod n$, where I used that $\gcd(x,n)|x$ to pull the $n$ aside. Going through, one sees that this gives $\gcd(x,n)$ different solutions $\mod n$.

Comment: Once one solution is known how do I find the others?

Comment: @user: I've added more. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You want to find number of $k$ (mod $N$) for which $\exists m$ satisfying $kx+mN =y$. Now such $k$ exist iff $\gcd(x,N)$ divides $y$ and in that case there are exactly $\gcd(x,N)$ solutions modulo $N$.